# Check if one list matches a sublist inside of a list by index

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

I have a data base that consist of about 800 16 number sequences. The sequences are a unique combination of ones and zeros. There is a process that outputs 15 of the numbers in the sequence and I want to look through the data base (historical data) and find all the matches excluding the last number. I started using a list of sublist. I adapted some code I found in another question asked, however it doesn't fully work for my application. The code is:

```
T = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
joined_T_Search = int(''.join(map(str,T_vein)))
joined_T_Search = str(joined_T_Search)
match_T = []    #empty list to append closest match to
#Match search algorithm
for text in data:
    if joined_T_Search in text:
        match_T.append(text)
 #grabs last digit to indicate hit/miss  
filter_output_T = match_T[0][15] #grabs last digit within sublist
print match_T
print len(match_T) #indicates if multiple results show up
```

It works well most of the time, however it sometimes outputs something like this:

```
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] #input
['0001000010000000', '1000010000000100', '0000100001000000', '0101000010000000', '0110100001000000', '0100001000000000', '1000010000000010', '1000010000000001', '1000100001000000', '1000010000001010', '0000100001000000', '0001000010000000', '0001000010000000', '0101100001000000', '1110000100000000', '0100100001000000', '0110000100000000', '1000010000000000'] #output
```

What I want (which it sometimes does if there are multiple similar combinations) is this:

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0] #input 
['1000001000100000', '1000001000100001', '1000001000100001', '1000001000100001'] #output
```

Ultimately, this last digit will be used to make a decision, so i will need to know its index. In the case of the first 15 matching and say 3 zeros and 2 ones appearing as the 16th number, I want to pick the most frequent number. This number could be appended to a list or similar method. It is important that the order of the numbers stay the same.

I think that a numpy 2D array is a better option then a list of list for a multitude of reasons, however I am not sure how to implement this.

I have only been coding in python for a few months, so I am just starting to get the hang of it. I have a mechanical engineering degree so I am familiar with programming but am by no means a programmer. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Will the input always be 15 characters and the outputs always be 16 characters?

Comment: Yes the input will always be 15 and the output 16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your problem correctly, I would do the following:

```
T = [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
joined_T_Search = ''.join(map(str,T))
match_T = []    #empty list to append closest match to

#Match search algorithm
for text in data:
    if joined_T_Search == text[:-1]:
        match_T.append(text[-1])
print match_T

if len(match_T) == 0:
    # Do something (nothing matched the input)
else:
    # Find the max of the last element
    print max(set(match_T), key=match_T.count)
```

This assumes that you only really care about the final digit that occurs most often. It's essentially what you were doing, but I only save the last digit and then find the max count of that set.

Comment: After a quick test, this appears to be working correctly. I am going to implement this into my program and check it across multiple scenarios. I will get back with you as soon as I can. Thank you @ Jenner Felton

Comment: @paperstsoap If the solution works for you, please accept it as the correct solution by clicking on the checkmark to the left.

Comment: I ran it over 20 cases. It worked perfectly in every case except when there is a case with equal number of results (such as one of the sequences ending with a 1 and one ending with a 0. This happened once out of the twenty cases. I don't expect it to happen often, however for completeness it probably should default one way or the other.

Comment: @paperstsoap When I have a case where it has an equal amount, it will default to whatever the first sequence found was. What would your preferred behavior be?

Comment: I ran some more test and it seems to lean towards a 1 in those situations.

Comment: @paperstsoap So you have a few options here. If you know that the last digit will be a 1 or 0, you can just compare `match_T.count(1) > match_T.count(0)` and decide what to do if they tie. If you might have more than 1's or 0's, you can sort the list and make your own max function to do whatever you want it to. Either way, I think the original problem has been solved and you should post another question if you have further issues.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on what to do if there is no matching sequence in the database?

Comment: @paperstsoap Is it giving you an error? What do you want it to do if there aren't any matching elements? The issue is probably that max needs arguments, so before you check for the max value, you can check `if len(match_T) == 0: #do whatever you want to do`.

Comment: It produces an error message for the line filter_T = max(set(match_T), key=match_T.count) : ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence. I tried adding that if statement before to just append a zero but I still got the same error.

Comment: @paperstsoap At this point, you should be able to solve these parts with a basic google search. That error is saying that you are giving max() an empty sequence. So...as I said above, you should check the length of the argument before you try to find the max of it. I'll edit the solution, but you should try to think the errors and the problems through before you ask.